# Dotted circle (U+25CC) with Arabic diacritics uncentered in XeLaTeX

Tags: arabic, diacritical-mark

I am trying to typeset the Arabic diacritics together with the dotted circle and for some reason, the diacritic is always un-centered.
I even tried `stackengine` to overlap them, but they are still off.

This is the "ideal" result I would like: [image] (from MS Word) and these are the outputs I get from LaTeX:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newfontfamily \arabfont {NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf}
\newcommand \arbtext [1] {{\LARGE\arabfont #1}}

\begin{document}
```

- `{\arbtext{\stackengine{1pt}{\symbol{"25CC}}{\symbol{"064F}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}` gives [image]
- `\arbtext{\char"064F\char"25CC}` gives [image]

I also tried placing the `U+25CC` after the diacritic, but that's even worse. Funnily, if I take the `U+25CC` out of the `\arabic` environment, the position is perfect, but the circled dot is not rendered.

- `{\char"25CC\arbtext{\char"064F}}` gives [image]

If relevant, I'm working in Overleaf and compiling with XeLaTeX (and I'm afraid I can't change either of these).

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with xetex

Comment: Well, thanks for the info, but it doesn't solve my problem :(